# Best JSON library to get JSON data for Django?

Tags: python, django, json

What is the best JSON library to get JSON data for Django, 'simplejson' or otherwise?

thanks very much

Comment: do you have any gripes with simplejson or are you wasting our time just for fun?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Python 2.6 comes with a [`json`](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html?highlight=json#module-json) module in the standard library -- so that would be best if you're on Python 2.6; for older Python versions, `simplejson` may be roughly equivalent.

Answer (score 9):

[Django itself integrates `simplejson`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/#id2) and has the ability to use your own version from the system if you have it installed.

```
from django.core import serializers
json_serializer = serializers.get_serializer("json")()
```

As Alex notes, the `json` module is bundled with Python 2.6 and above -- that's actually simplejson source pulled into Python core.  This might demonstrate to you that it has *wide* acceptance in the Python community.

The reason that you may want to use your own version is that `simplejson` when compiled with C extensions and `cjson`, a different module, are substantially more performant than the versions bundled with Django or Python.

Comment: Actually, `django.contrib.simplejson` will use the standard library `json` module if it's available. That is, on Python 2.6+, `from django.utils import simplejson` will actually give you back the standard library's `json` module. The stdlib module, in turn, transparently loads the C extension if it's available

So, if you're using Django, there's no good reason not to always use `django.utils simplejson`.